# How to I specify that a match should occur if a character does not belong to an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, ruby-2.4

I'm having trouble specifying "the next character should not be from this group of characters" in my regex.  I have

```
TOKENS = [":", ".", "'"]
"01:39\t" =~  /\b0\d[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]\d\d^#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/
 #=> nil
```

Since `"\t"` is not part of my `TOKENS` array,  I would think the above should match, but it does not.  How do I adjust my regex, specifically this part

```
^#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}
```

to say that the character should not be part of this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need brackets around the "not" portion of the regex.

```
>> TOKENS = [":", ".", "'"]
>> regex = /\b0\d[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]\d\d^#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/
>> "01:39\t" =~ regex
#=> nil
```

However:

```
>> regex = /\b0\d[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]\d\d[^#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]/
# Add brackets                            here^                and here^
>> "01:39\t" =~ regex
#=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/\b0\d[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}]\d\d^#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}/` pattern will finally look like

```
/(?-mix:\b0\d[(?-mix::|\.|')]\d\d^(?-mix::|\.|'))/
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, the regex object is a modifier group with disabled multiline, case insensitive and free spacing modes. The last `^` is the start of the line anchor, and it alone ruins the whole regex turning it into a pattern that never matches any string.

It is not enough to wrap the `#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}`  with `[...]` character class brackets, you would need to use the *`.source`* property to get rid of `(?-mix:...)` since you do not want to negate `m`, `i`, `x`, etc. *However*, you just can't use `Regexp.union` since it will add `|` char and inside a character class, it is treated as a literal char (so, you will also negate pipes).

You should define the separator sequence with `TOKENS.join().gsub(/[\]\[\^\\-]/, '\\\\\\&')` to escape all chars that should be escaped inside a regex character class and then place in between character class square brackets.

[Ruby demo:](https://ideone.com/p7aBsd)

```
TOKENS = [":", ".", "'", "]"]
sep_rx = TOKENS.join().gsub(/[\]\[\^\\-]/, '\\\\\\&')
puts sep_rx
# => :.'\]
rx = /\b0\d[#{sep_rx}]\d\d[^#{sep_rx}]/
puts rx.source
# => \b0\d[:.'\]]\d\d[^:.'\]]
puts "01:39\t" =~  rx
# => 0
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/Und7JEyTq2)

Note that `.gsub(/[\]\[\^\\-]/, '\\\\\\&')` matches `]`, `[`, `^`, `\` and `-` and adds a backslash in front of them. The first 4 backslashes in `'\\\\\\&'` define a literal backslash in the replacement pattern and `\\&` stands for the whole match